# Problem with rtabmap_ros and nonfree OpenCV

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to use rtabmap_ros with SIFT and SURF. I've installed nonfree OpenCV and can find the folder in /usr/include/opencv2. For some reason though whenever I run rtabmap_ros I get the message

```
[ WARN] (2016-04-15 10:21:56.026) Features2d.cpp:349::create() SURF/SIFT features cannot be used because OpenCV was not built with nonfree module. ORB is used instead.
```

Anyone know why rtabmap_ros can't find nonfree?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232015/problem-with-rtabmap_ros-and-nonfree-opencv/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2016-04-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bluking](https://answers.ros.org/users/24456/bluking/) on 2016-04-18**:
you can check nonfree module is true or not when you catkin_make you project, if not, please build the opencv with source code , follow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781617/how-to-install-opencv-3-0-with-nonfree-module)

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-18**:
They were installed. As matlabbe said, I needed to do a clean build of rtabmap from source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Make sure to do a clean build of `rtabmap` after OpenCV (with nonfree) is installed ([step 2 here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#build-from-source)):

```
$ cd rtabmap/build
$ rm -r *
$ cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=~/catkin_ws/devel ..
$ make
$ make install
```

When you do `$ cmake ..`, make sure you see in the info at the end that OpenCV version with nonfree is detected.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-04-15**:
Yup, that did it. Thanks